# Browser trying to save code as file name

Tags: internet-explorer

Our company uses a third party web application that dozens of people use, but occasionally decides not to download files properly to a handful of users.  The download appears to be handled by an ASPX page, but rather than sending the browser an actual file, you get the tail end of the code intended to trigger the download.  Please see the image below.

[image: Error image]

No matter what you do, this results in an empty file with code as the file name.  If we switch to Chrome it works fine.  And only a handful of users are affected at any given time.  This seems to happen regardless of whether a user is in the office, at home, or on VPN from home.  Nothing has changed in our networks, and everyone is on the same anti-virus.

Does anyone have a clue what this is called, or what causes it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]  To address the "unclear" status, this is the clearest I can explain it since I have no earthly idea what is causing this behavior in the browser.  I'm hoping someone with a more intimate knowledge of how webapps call on the browser to download files will be able to decipher what's going on from the screenshot, which is why I brought my question to Stackexchange.  The more eyes that see it, the more likely someone might recognize the behavior and proffer an explanation.

Comment: What web application are you talking about? Does the same happens if you use Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: The application is called Yardi, it's a proprietary accounting application.  This doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox, but Yardi only officially supports IE, so I have to do my best to make sure it works.

And this behavior seems to be transient.  It will happen to a few people for a week or so, then go back to normal.  Then a few months later, a handful of other people in the same office will start having the same issue.  And so on...

Comment: What version of IE and Windows are you using? Have you tried on safe mode?

Comment: Win 7 Pro x64 with IE 11 company-wide.  And safe mode makes no difference, nor do we allow users to install addons.